# Gerrit Project Branch Permission

Tags: git, gerrit

**My Gerrit Version is -2.10.2**

I have one gerrit project in that I have two branches `Master` and `Release_Branch` in this I want to restrict the branch permissions, Means `Master` branch should not be accessed by `Release_Branch` team members. Similarly `Release_Branch` should not be accessed by `Master` branch users.

For the same I have created two groups in gerrit and created the access like below,

```
Reference: refs/heads/Release_Branch/*
```

**Permissions Settings:**

```
Read - Release_branch_Group
Create Reference - Release_branch_Group
Push - Release_branch_Group
Push Merge Commit - Release_branch_Group
Label Code-Review - Release_branch_Group
Submit - Release_branch_Group
```

Still when we tried to clone the (Release_Branch) from user’s machine with below command, it shows below error.

```
git clone --single-branch -b Release_Branch ssh://ramesh.s@ss-gerrit-server:29418/test
```

**Error:**

```
Cloning into 'test'...
warning: Could not find remote branch Release_Branch to clone.
fatal: could not fetch refs from ssh://ramesh.s@ss-gerrit-server:29418/test
```

Could someone assist me to fix the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your branch is named "Release_Branch" then you need to change:

```
Reference: refs/heads/Release_Branch/*
```

To:

```
Reference: refs/heads/Release_Branch
```

The first one grant permissions to branches like "Release_Branch/foo" or "Release_Branch/boo".